# Does sjcl support arraybuffers?

Tags: javascript, encryption, sjcl

I'm trying to use sjcl to encrypt and then decrypt an arraybuffer. I can see in the source that sjcl has a codec for arraybuffer but I just can't figure out how to use it:

```
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(64);
const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
console.log(view.length)
var encrypted = sjcl.encrypt("password", buffer)
console.log(encrypted.length)
var decrypted = sjcl.decrypt("password", encrypted)
console.log(decrypted.length)
```

The first console.log() prints 64 (which makes sense). The second console.log() prints 150 (the size of the encrypted results)... But the third console.log always prints 0.

Answer (score 2):

The usage and documentation on sjcl is as cryptic as it's purpose but what you want to achieve is possible of course.

First you have to use the **arrayBufferCodec** codec to translate your ArrayBuffer to sjcl's own internal bitArray representation. Afterwards this needs to be translated once more to a Base64 string which can be fed to the `sjcl.encrypt()` method. The reverse of this procedure will give you back your original ArrayBuffer.

Here's an example:

```js
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(64);
var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

for (var i = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
  view[i] = i;
}

var arrayBufferBits = sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer.toBits(buffer);
var base64String = sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(arrayBufferBits);
var encrypted = sjcl.encrypt("password", base64String);

var decrypted = sjcl.decrypt("password", encrypted);
var base64Bits = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits(decrypted);
var buffer2 = sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer.fromBits(base64Bits);

view = new Uint8Array(buffer2);
console.log(view);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/sjcl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sjcl@1.0.8/core/codecArrayBuffer.js"></script>
```

Comment: `sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer.toBits` throws this for me: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_sjcl.default.codec.arrayBuffer.toBits')`. I'm trying to decrypt an ArrayBuffer. Can't get it work...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Neneil, answer from @obscure try to use `sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer.toBits` to convert an ArrayBuffer to sjcl's bitArray. Based on the documentation of [`sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer`](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer.html), it has only two methods `fromBits()` and `hexDumpBuffer()`, and **no method named `toBits()` is defined in old version**, that is why @Neneil encounter the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_sjcl.default.codec.arrayBuffer.toBits')`. In the [latest version 1.0.8](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sjcl@1.0.8/core/codecArrayBuffer.js), `toBits()` has been defined.

To encrypt and then decrypt an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), another way is just **working on [TypedArrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) without converting to plain text**, though under the context of encryption and decryption plain text is expected.

Detailed steps are:

1. first create an [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) backed by the ArrayBuffer,
2. then further covert the TypedArray to sjcl's [bitArray](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/bitArray.js.html) by [`sjcl.codec.bytes.toBits()`](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/sjcl.codec.bytes.html), since sjcl does all computation on bitArrays.
3. Next use `sjcl.encrypt()` to encrypt it.
4. For decryption, use [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) to convert the decryped plain text to a stream of UTF-8 bytes, and the ArrayBuffer associated with this Uint8Array can be accessed using the `buffer` property.

Here is an example:

```js
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(64);
let view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

for (var i = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
  view[i] = i;
}

const sjcl_bits = sjcl.codec.bytes.toBits(view);
const encrypted = sjcl.encrypt("password", sjcl_bits);

const decrypted = sjcl.decrypt("password", encrypted);
const decrypted_uint8Array = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(decrypted);

console.log(decrypted_uint8Array);

// access the associated ArrayBuffer using buffer property
const decryped_buffer = decrypted_uint8Array.buffer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sjcl@1.0.8/sjcl.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sjcl@1.0.8/core/codecBytes.min.js"></script>
```